How should I configure the parameters of the people-polkadot archive node ？
below are my configuration parameters, but the node cannot run. I think there is something wrong with my parameter configuration
Parachain Arguments：
--base-path=/chain-data
--rpc-cors=all
--port=21780
--in-peers=25
--out-peers=25
--node-key= **
--rpc-external
--pruning=archive
--rpc-methods=Unsafe
--name=people-polkadot
--chain=people-polkadot
Relaychain Arguments：
--rpc-cors=all
--port=24062
--rpc-port=9934
--node-key=**
--rpc-external
--no-telemetry
--name=people-polkadot
--in-peers=25
--out-peers=25
--in-peers-light=0
Below is my error log：
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

thread 'main' panicked at cumulus/polkadot-parachain/src/chain_spec/people.rs:67:17:

not yet implemented: Generate chain-spec: ../../chain-specs/people-polkadot.json

stack backtrace:

0: rust_begin_unwind

1: core::panicking::panic_fmt

2: polkadot_parachain::chain_spec::people::PeopleRuntimeType::load_config

3: polkadot_parachain::command::load_spec

4: sc_cli::config::CliConfiguration::create_configuration

5: polkadot_parachain::command::run

6: polkadot_parachain::main

note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.


Need more detail to reopen this. E.G. What error did you encounter?

I have added my error log

"not yet implemented" sounds like you hit an unimplemented!() in the code - maybe try a later version of the code?
